# Django csrf token not sent with ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

I'm trying to post some data through jQuery AJAX to a Django (1.4) view.  I've done this before, but something isn't right this time around.  I've done my AJAX set up to include the CSFR token as explained in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

jQuery along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/login/',
        type:'POST',
        contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8;',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username:$('#this').val(),
            password:$('#that').val()
        })
```

However, when I send the data, when I include the line in the view:

```
 print request.raw_post_data
```

it will print twice.  The first time with the posted data as a QueryDict {u'this':u'these', u'that':u'those'}, and the second time with csrfmiddleware token.

Why is printing two times?  Shouldn't they be in the same QueryDic?

Comment: I also get this error `"Key this' not found in <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'yadjaklfjlajd]}>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had not included

```
e.preventDefault()
```

the form was sending twice.  One QueryDict was valid but the view function didn't process b/c the default submit data only had the csrftoken.

Used

```
simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
```

to get my data.